# macOS boots after internet recovery - but recovery partition does not. How to repair?

Tags: partition, startup, recovery, repair, internet-recovery

After a successful internet recovery, the OS boots - but the local recovery partition still appears to be messed up - it just hangs on the gray Apple screen indefinitely after using `Alt/Opt` to access the boot menu.

The machine in question is a Mac Mini ~2010.

I've exhausted the solutions I can find - in part because the search results are so spammy. Any advice would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: If could create a USB flash drive OS X/macOS installer, backup important files (if any), then boot from the flash drive, erase the internal drive(s) and do a clean install.

Comment: Since your Mac is bootable, you should be able to exactly identify your Mac's model/year, the version of OS X/macOS you are using and post the output from `diskutil list`. This would aid in generating other possible answers.